# submit MVC form without postback and execute javascript soon after

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, submit, postback

Can anyone please tell me that how to submit MVC form using JQuery or any other way in which I want to submit form after updating fields to save it in database and then return JSON result and then display a message for success using javascript. I found plenty of codes but still unable to fulfill my requirement.

First solution is to use Ajax call to achieve this. Here is sample javascript code but I am unable to trigger default MVC validations:

```
var form = $('#formId');
$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  async: true,
  type: "POST",
  url: form.attr('action'),
  data: form.serialize(),
  success: function (data) {
    alert(data);
 }
});
```

Another solution I tried is using ViewBag but I don't want postback.

I don't want to return View() and reload all of my dropdowns in Post Action.
I tried postback but how can we return Object containing message?

Comment: ajax call should do it! what exactly is the problem with the ajax call?

Comment: What do you mean _"trigger default MVC validations"_? Do you have client side validation enabled? How are you calling this script. If you want the error messages generated by server side validation to be returned, then you need to get them from `ModelState` and return them in your json response.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Client side validation is enabled. I am calling on button press. and I am asking about triggering client side errors using javascript.  above solution is perfect if my client side validation triggered by javascript. validation (defined at data notation) is working fine when I post this form using input type="submit".

Comment: @psylogic just issue is to trigger mvc validation by javascript.

Comment: So is the button just `type="button"` (not `type="submit"`)?

Comment: No matter what we use. <button, <input type="submit" or <input type="button". all should work...

Comment: `type="button"` would not work - its not calling the validator. Try adding `form.validate();` immediately after `var form = $('#formId');`